# Discord music bot - ctx is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord, bots

How can ı fix this

```
async def join(self, ctx):
if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send('Bir ses kanalında değilsiniz')
voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
if ctx.voice_client is None:
    await voice_channel.connect()
else:
    await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
```

ctx is a required argument that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `self` unless you are inside of a class. Even then, I don't think you are supposed to be inside of a class.

If you are using the default way of running a discord.py bot, you still shouldn't need it because ctx acts as self.

Answer (score -1):

Unless that is inside a class deriving from a cog don't use `self`.

---

P.S. I hope that is not the actual indentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).